# Why can't I close or dismiss a Javascript alert in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

**Situation:** I invoke a Javascript `alert` through the `UIWebView` method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` like this...

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('FOOBAR');"];
```

**Problem:** iOS displays an alert saying "FOOBAR" as expected, but tapping on the "Close" button does not dismiss the alert.

Why can't I close the Javascript alert?  How do I get it to close?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question gave me the most insight to the problem...

[Deadlock with GCD and webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531701/deadlock-with-gcd-and-webview)

The gist is that the thread handling the JS from the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method and the thread handling the iOS alert view are probably blocking each other, making the "Close" button unresponsive.

My workaround is to defer the JS `alert` with a `setTimeout`, something like this...

```
NSString *jsMyAlert = @"setTimeout(function(){alert('FOOBAR');}, 1);";

[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsMyAlert];
```

To avoid any risk of deadlock, it might be better to have the `UIWebView` trigger an `UIAlertView` rather than rely on `UIWebView` to handle the JS `alert`.  The workaround above would be suitable for most debugging purposes though.

Comment: This bug is still in iOS 9...sigh.

Comment: Still in iOS 11