# Unable to dismiss js alert message, some deadlock happening

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I am using UIWebView, while uploading images, sometimes iOS giving warning as

```
Not an accepted type
```

alert, with ok button, when I click ok, alertview is not dismissed.

Is there any way to close alert from url loaded in uiwebview.

I found similar links below:

[Why can't I close or dismiss a Javascript alert in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833840/why-cant-i-close-or-dismiss-a-javascript-alert-in-uiwebview)
[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString hangs on iOS5.0/5.1 when called using GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593900/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-hangs-on-ios5-0-5-1-when-called#comment29257640_11593900)

But not sure how to do it in Xamarin.

Comment: Please someone give me idea what's going on, since alert is not being dismissed, app is getting stuck and I have to remove app from recent list to make it normal

Comment: Can you post your code how you initialize your UIAlertView?

Comment: @BUKA, I am not using UIAlertView, alert is triggered by iOS itself, as warning while trying to upload image file

Comment: Have you checked the same process(uploading an image) in safari?  Look [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47524/webview-input-type-file-not-working), maybe somehow it helps

Comment: Yes, in safari also, its showing warning, but if I click ok, it dismisses the warning message, whereas in UIWebview its making the app stuck.