# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString ios Hangs UI

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7, uiwebview, grand-central-dispatch

I have to call this method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString every second to update the UI of an Webview.
My UI gets hang for a while when ever the method gets called.
The following code snippet didn't solved my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];

    });
    });
```

Comment: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString blocks the thread that it runs on.

Comment: Therefore you need to make your java script quicker, or broken down into smaller quick steps

Answer (score 0):

Some searching around shows that wrapping in `GCD` block could potentially be a bug and doing this following *helps*:

```
[webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:string waitUntilDone:NO];
```

However, `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` has to be called on the main thread which if your `string` variable is lengthy `js` there maybe no way to smooth it out from the `obj-c` side. You could try optimizing your `js` code.

Comment: How would this stop the gui from hanging?

Comment: Depending on how complex your `js` code is it won't. What I saw was that there was a bug filed in wrapping the call in blocks was causing a longer UI lock. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593900/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-hangs-on-ios5-0-5-1-when-called

Comment: Useful to know. However I think the op has found the call to stringByEvalutingJavaScriptFromString was slow and so he wrapped it in dispatch_async because he thought that makes it run asynchronously and thus would stop the gui freezing. "The following code snippet didn't solved my problem" i.e. the code is an attempt at a solution to solve code that is already hanging

Comment: The problem is that `stringByEvalutingJavaScriptFromString` is part of `UIKit` which has to be called from the main thread. I saw some other hacks to *try* and get around it but nothing pretty. Also, I though the OP said the accepted answer fixed his problem??

Comment: Out of curiosity did you try changing it to `performSelectorOnMainThread` ?? I'm curious if it did anything at all

Comment: couldnt able to resolve with any of them, Actually i am updating Highcharts in the HTML,which are in UIWebView,while updating the highchart dynamically, adding point one by on,e the GUI freezes for a while when ever added one point.