# How to display a JavaScript alert dialog in UIWebView using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString but not performSelectorOnMainThread in Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, performselector, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

In Objective-C, the following code works in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.myWebView performSelectorOnMainThread:
@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)
withObject:@"alert('Test')" waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This code is suggested by this:

[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString hangs on iOS5.0/5.1 when called using GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593900/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-hangs-on-ios5-0-5-1-when-called)

It says that `performSelectorOnMainThread` works with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. This brings out an alert dialog and it can be closed by clicking the OK button. However, `dispatch_async` does not work and the dialog freezes and the OK button cannot be pressed.

The question is: How to make the above function of dialog work in Swift? How to convert the code into Swift?

The problem is that `performSelectorOnMainThread` used in Objective-C is not usable in Swift.

If I directly call the below code in `viewDidLoad`, the device is suspended with the LaunchScreen:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("alert('test')");
```

I have tried the [Alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift) to `performSelectorOnMainThread` but the results are either a frozen LaunchScreen or a frozen alert dialog.

Can somebody please tell me how to call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to display a JavaScript alert dialog in Swift? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by loading a web page and call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` in `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

The solution is as below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var myPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
        myWebView.delegate = self
        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: myPath!)!))
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("alert('Hello')")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```